# How to make an array from for loop globally available in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, for-loop, julia, global-variables

I am writing a code in Julia. Here, I have a dataframe of size 272x32. My objective is to find the minimum in each column, and store them in an array of 32 elements. To execute this I have created a for loop iterating over the range of columns in dataframe. However, upon assigning the values to be global the output stored has only the last value. But, I would like it to have minimum of column as each entry in array which I can use it for matrix arithmetic operations.

The code snippet:

```
n = ncol(variables)

for i in 1:n

    global mins = minimum(variables[!, i])
    global maxs = maximum(variables[!, i])

end
```

Please advice to resolve this issue.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you are asking for but it seems it is:

```
mins = minimum.(eachcol(variables))
maxs = maximum.(eachcol(variables))
```

Comment: Thank you @Bogumil Kaminski for the suggestion, it does solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more approach to solve this issue,

```
mins = zeros(n)
maxs = zeros(n)
n = ncol(variables)

for i in 1:n

    mins[i] = minimum(variables[!, i])
    maxs[i] = maximum(variables[!, i])

end
```

But I don't know how it will affect the execution speed or memory allocation?